# redirect callout to mock callout

Tags: unit-test, httpcalloutmock

I have a utility `class` where we use to call when making request. This request can be with different `classes` that uses the this utility `class`.

Here is the sample:

```
public with sharing class SampleAPIUtility 
{    
   public static String ConnectToSampleAPI(String jsonRequest)
   {

       HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
       req.setEndpoint('https://test.com/Api/Test/');
       req.setMethod('POST');

       req.SetBody(jsonRequest);
       req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
       req.setTimeout(120000);
       req.setHeader('Content-Length', '300000'); 

       Http http = new Http(); 
       HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);

       return res.getBody();
   }
}
```

Here is the sample class with method that uses the utility class above:

```
global with sharing class ImportRecord implements Schedulable
{
   //Omitted some codes
   @future (callout=true)
   public static void SampleImportRecord()
   {
       //omitted some codes

       jsonQuery = SampleAPIUtility.GetObjectJSONString(id);
       jsonOutput = '';
       if(!Test.isRunningTest())
           jsonOutput = SampleAPIUtility.ConnectToSampleAPI(jsonQuery);

       //ommitted some codes

   }

   //omitted some codes
}
```

Here is the class for mock callout:

```
@isTest
public class TestHttpResponseGenerator implements HttpCalloutMock 
{
   // Implement this interface method
   public HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) 
   {
       HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
       res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
       res.setBody(TestHttpResponseResult.GetObjectJSONResult());
       res.setStatusCode(200);
       return res;
    }
}
```

Test Method:

```
@isTest
private class ImportRecordTest {

    static testMethod void testImportRecord() {

        //omitted codes

        Test.startTest();
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new TestHttpResponseGenerator());
        String schedule = '0 0 0 * * ?';        
        system.schedule('Testing ImportRecordClass', schedule, new ImportRecord()); 
        Test.stopTest();
   }
}
```

First, the `TestHttpResponseResult.GetObjectJSONResult()` is just a class with a method that return string in a json format. How can I use the mockhttpcallout in Utility class that is being use in different class with different set of json string. I want this `SampleAPIUtility.ConnectToSampleAPI(jsonQuery);` to access the response of the mockcallout instead of the response from the external server. Would there be a way to do that?

Comment: Does your test method make use of the Test.setMock() method?

Comment: yes. Oh! I forgot to include the test method.

Comment: Is it working? From what I see here, if you get rid of the: if(!Test.isRunningTest())  you should be fine.

Comment: @martin, no it's not. the external callout is used with different request. how am I able to know which test request I'm getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, sometime before you make the external callout, you are going to want to create an instance of your mock responder:

```
TestHttpResponseGenerator thrg = new TestHttpResponseGenerator();
```

And then set the mock for the test:

```
Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, thrg);
```

Also, at some point you will have to get rid of this line:

```
if(!Test.isRunningTest())
```

You should also surround your callout in the test method with:

```
Test.startTest();
//callout
Test.stopTest();
```

stopTest() will get all of the pending async processes to be run synchronously.

Update:
If you want your httpresponder mock test class to be able to provide different responses, you could do something like this:

```
@isTest
public class TestHttpResponseGenerator implements HttpCalloutMock 
{
   String theJSONResponse;

   public TestHttpResponseGenerator(/* some parameter to indicate which response you want */){
       this.theJSONResponse =  TestHttpResponseResult.GetObjectJSONResult(/* that parameter */);
   }
   // Implement this interface method
   public HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) 
   {
       HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
       res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
       res.setBody(theJSONResponse);
       res.setStatusCode(200);
       return res;
    }
}
```

Then you can create test methods for each of the possible return values of the service you are working with by setting that value in the constructor of the mock. By the way, you should probably also make the status code settable in a similar way since you aren't always going to be guaranteed to get a 200 response.

Comment: Oh! I never thought of using the constructor to pass the type of response.

Comment: for some reason it's not getting the response from the mockcallout. mockcallout work whenever there is a callout right?

Comment: @robertpeter07 Yes, it should always provide the response that you return in the respond method. I don't know if you've changed your code since the last edit on this site, but one issue could be this line: if(!Test.isRunningTest()) is preventing the callout from happening during the test.

Comment: i have removed that. does the schedule matter?

Comment: @robertpeter07 It should be happening when you call Test.stopTest().

Comment: There is something wrong why the mockcallout does not work. Does the api version matter? I think we are using version 2.x in the callout class that we are using.

Comment: @robertpeter07 Is the api version >= 26? Apparently the setMock feature didn't come about until Winter 13. http://blog.force365.com/2012/08/30/salesforce-winter-13-force-top-10/

Comment: I updated the api version seems we were using version 25. But still not working, would the return type of this `public static String ConnectToSampleAPI(String jsonRequest)` has something to do with the return type of the mockcallout which is returning the whole response instead of the `res.getBody()`?

Comment: @robertpeter07 I doubt it, the response should be returned from the mock here: HTTPResponse res = http.send(req); Since that method then takes the body of the response and just returns that string, you should be fine.

Comment: @robertpeter07  I doubt it, the response should be returned from the mock here: HTTPResponse res = http.send(req); Since your **ConnectToSampleAPI** method then takes the body of the response and just returns that string, you should be fine.